# Inhibiting repetition with user input

Tags: ruby, gets

I need a code that collects a user's input with `gets.chomp`, and if they repeat the same answer twice, it will read an error message. What is the best method to do this? Is there a way to collect the answers and then continue to check for duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Keep an history of answers.

```
history = []

loop do
  answer = gets.chomp
  if history.include? answer
    puts "already answered"
    next
  else
    history.push answer
  end

  # do something
end
```

Comment: My code works now! Thank you a million times over Ursus. Cheers <3